# Can rotations be controlled with Nimfa's models in Python?

Tags: python, matrix-factorization

I am using Nimfa package to perform non negative matrix factorization and would like to know if there is a way to control rotation.

i.e : I want to implement a parameter (similar to FPeak in  Positive Matrix Factorization) which would approximate the rotational ambiguity of factor analysis (resulting in non-uniqueness of W and H in the decomposition : V = W*H)